# Are there any pictures of the Qualifications for Astronauts hearing for the House of Representatives?

Tags: history, project-mercury, astronaut-recruitment

On July 17th and 18th, 1962, a hearing was organized in front of Congress for the special subcommittee on the selection of astronauts. This hearing was organized to ascertain whether women could be selected as astronauts, following the [Mercury 13 tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_13).

I've been reading the transcripts of this hearing, and trying to imagine what the hearing might have looked like. Does any photo-documentation of this audience exist ?

Comment: where can you find the transcripts for the hearing?

Comment: @ani https://web.archive.org/web/20151211072933/http://nasa.lu/static/qualifications_for_astronauts_hearing_1962.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Although this doesn't really look like a Congressional hearing photo, the source claims it is. The legend says "Jerrie Cobb and Janey Hart testifying before congress. (Netflix)"

It may look like this because the testimony was before a Subcommittee and not the full Congress:

> Subcommittee of the House Committee on Science and Astronautics,
> headed by Rep. Victor AnCuso, opened hearings on the role of
> women in the space program. Jane B. Hart and Jerrie Cobb,
> representing the 13 women who completed unofficial space quali-
> fication tests a t the Lovelace Foundation, testified that women
> had a real contribution to make and were qualified as astronauts.
> Jacqueline Cochran, well-known flier, said that "there is no doubt
> in the world that women will go into space.”

([1962 NASA chronology](https://history.nasa.gov/AAchronologies/1962.pdf))

[image]

> Janey Hart and Jerrie Cobb flew to Washington to try and change their minds. **On July 17, 1962 Hart and Cobb testified before congress.** Hart's statement began, "It will perhaps come as no surprise to you that I strongly believe women should have a role in space research. In fact, it is inconceivable to me that the world of outer space should be restricted to men only, like some sort of stag club."

(emphasis mine)

Source: [Right stuff, wrong gender — the true story of the women who almost went to the moon](https://www.cbc.ca/radio/quirks/scrap-medical-weed-women-in-space-and-more-1.4636793/right-stuff-wrong-gender-the-true-story-of-the-women-who-almost-went-to-the-moon-1.4636802)

Answer (score 1):

The [library of Congress has a picture of these hearings](https://www.loc.gov/pictures/item/98512125/), although it appears to be under copyright, so only a thumbnail of the picture is available on the LOC website.

[image]